# podman build throws an Error: no FROM statement found

Tags: mysql, podman

I have following `Dockerfile` to build `mysql` image under `/opt/docker/mysql/Dockerfile`.

```
FROM mysql:5.7
...
```

And here is `db.yml` file that uses above file under `/opt/docker/db.yml`.

```
# mysql/db yaml
version: '3.7'

volumes:
  foodb: {}

services:
  db:
    build:
      context: ./mysql
      network: host
      args:
        - app_dir=foo
    expose:
       - "3306"
    ports:
       - "3306:3306" # For dev debugging
    volumes:
      - "foodb:/var/lib/mysql"
```

I launched following `podman` cmd to build its image.

```
podman build -f ./db.yml
```

Then it threw `Error: no FROM statement found`. From my quick research, I ran into a few saying using old podman may cause this error however I have pretty recent `podman` and `podman-compose` installed on `rhel 8` server.

```
podman-compose version: 1.0.6
['podman', '--version', '']
using podman version: 4.4.1
```

I have to say I was able to build docker image just fine with docker however once I switched to podman I ran into this problem.

I'd greatly appreciate someone can explain to me what causes this error.